# Android webview scaling different

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, webview

I have a problem with my Android webview in my app scaling my site differently than on the browser on my Android on my s5. On my s5 my jquery mobile header scales nicely and badge looks good, however, on my app (only on the s5) the header is small comparatively and the badger is off. This problem doesn't occur on my s7 edge or on my iOS app/safari.

I set the viewport in html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

and I set webview variables as such

```
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

[View on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYORG.png)

[View on webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXVu.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: did you set setInitialScale???

Comment: Hi @sasikumar, I have tried webView.setInitialScale(1); which didn't seem to do anything. Trying different values didn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: this may be helpful https://asherson.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/android-webview-scaling/

Comment: Good link, unfortunately nothing seems to help. I'm baffled by what could be  causing this problem.

Comment: @thailey01 Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue....